# JupyterLab: How do I set JupyterLab/Hub to only allow a user to use 1 active workspace at a time?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I'm running a newly migrated multi-user deployment of JupyterLab, and I'm currently trying to replicate the behavior that was present on the last server onto the new one, but one feature continues to elude me. On the previous server if I had one tab open running JupyterLab and tried to open a new one, I would receive this error message in the browser for the new tab:

[image]

However, on the new JupyterLab server, opening a new tab of JupyterLab when one is running will just automatically create a new workspace, with the url looking like so:

[image]

My question is this: **How do I redirect a user to same workspace, and not auto-generate new workspaces when one is already active?**

Comment: I was thinking that maybe this feature is defined in the Dockerfile, namely in the command `CMD ["jupyterhub-singleuser"]`.  However, writing this into the config file as `c.Spawner.cmd = ['jupyterhub-singleuser']` only changed the user layout to look just like the jupyter notebook UI. Now I'm thinking maybe this is a new version feature, since the new server has 1.4.2 installed, and the old was using verion 0.9.4